# How to Make POJO class when response have mix data. some key contain Object and some have array type data

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, gson

I am using **retrofit2** to Make network request,I have searched over here but my bad luck i couldn't find any working solution. that's why i am putting my question here.
my **JSON respons**e is given below.

The problem is sometimes the REST API returns an Array of **hour** , but sometimes it is just a **Object**. **How does one handle such a situation**? 
Is there an **elegant** way to handle a mixed array like this in Retrofit/Gson? I'm not responsible for the data coming from the API, so I don't think changing that will be an option.Any help would be appreciated.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [


        {
            "id": 30,
            "name": "Rh.poutiqe",
            "global_delay": "0",
            "approved": true,
            "min_order": "0.000",
            "has_pickup": 0,
            "address": {
                "id": "35",
                "name": "Store Address",
                "type": "house",
                "block_number": "8",
                "street": "85",
                "avenue": "0",
                "building": "2",
                "floor": "",
                "apartment": "",
                "directions": "",
                "lat": null,
                "lng": null,
                "city": {
                    "id": "79",
                    "name": "Bayan",
                    "zone": "3",
                    "governate": "Hawally"
                }
            },
            "status": "Available",
            "owner": {
                "id": "32",
                "username": "+96550199900",
                "creation_date": "2017-08-07 09:46:49",
                "info": {
                    "name": "Asmaa alkandri",
                    "email": "Asooma_q8@hotmail.com",
                    "mobile": "50199900",
                    "store_id": "30",
                    "device_token": "e01efb2f03cd43509242c7b38ca890471db2e5b056f50b7a3661c34ab45b0b6e"
                },
                "addresses": [
                    {
                        "id": "35",
                        "name": "Store Address",
                        "type": "house",
                        "block_number": "8",
                        "street": "85",
                        "avenue": "0",
                        "building": "2",
                        "floor": "",
                        "apartment": "",
                        "directions": "",
                        "lat": null,
                        "lng": null,
                        "city": {
                            "id": "79",
                            "name": "Bayan",
                            "zone": "3",
                            "governate": "Hawally"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "open": false,
            "image": {
                "src": "https://api.bits.com.kw/assets/stores/30/y1nzl.jpg"
            },
            "hours": {
                "2": [
                    {
                        "id": "117",
                        "day_id": "2",
                        "day_of_week": "Tuesday",
                        "start_hour": "1400",
                        "end_hour": "2300"
                    }
                ],
                "3": [
                    {
                        "id": "118",
                        "day_id": "3",
                        "day_of_week": "Wednesday",
                        "start_hour": "1400",
                        "end_hour": "2300"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "next_available": {
                "day_of_week": "Tuesday",
                "start_hour": "1400",
                "end_hour": "2300",
                "day_id": "2",
                "date": "2017-09-19"
            }
        },

         {
            "id": 57,
            "name": "RH Kitchen",
            "global_delay": "0",
            "approved": true,
            "min_order": "0.000",
            "has_pickup": 0,
            "address": {
                "id": "63",
                "name": "Store Address",
                "type": "house",
                "block_number": "5",
                "street": "2",
                "avenue": "",
                "building": "97",
                "floor": "",
                "apartment": "",
                "directions": "",
                "lat": null,
                "lng": null,
                "city": {
                    "id": "79",
                    "name": "Bayan",
                    "zone": "3",
                    "governate": "Hawally"
                }
            },
            "status": "Not Receiving Orders",
            "owner": {
                "id": "57",
                "username": "+96566659454",
                "creation_date": "2017-09-09 11:32:19",
                "info": {
                    "name": "RH Kitchen",
                    "email": "taiba.aldarmi@gmail.com",
                    "mobile": "66659454",
                    "store_id": "57",
                    "device_token": "f6fffd3a393e9aea53863cffbb55b51a3afd2475e952091ea362a85fc930ec9a"
                },
                "addresses": [
                    {
                        "id": "63",
                        "name": "Store Address",
                        "type": "house",
                        "block_number": "5",
                        "street": "2",
                        "avenue": "",
                        "building": "97",
                        "floor": "",
                        "apartment": "",
                        "directions": "",
                        "lat": null,
                        "lng": null,
                        "city": {
                            "id": "79",
                            "name": "Bayan",
                            "zone": "3",
                            "governate": "Hawally"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "open": false,
            "image": {
                "src": "https://api.bits.com.kw/placeholder.jpg"
            },
            "hours": [],
            "next_available": false
        },
        {
            "id": 64,
            "name": "Lets__shop",
            "global_delay": "1440",
            "approved": true,
            "min_order": "5.000",
            "has_pickup": 0,
            "address": {
                "id": "64",
                "name": "Store Address",
                "type": "house",
                "block_number": "3",
                "street": "312",
                "avenue": "",
                "building": "56",
                "floor": "",
                "apartment": "",
                "directions": "",
                "lat": "0.000000000000000000",
                "lng": "0.000000000000000000",
                "city": {
                    "id": "126",
                    "name": "Saad Al Abdullah",
                    "zone": "9",
                    "governate": "Jahra"
                }
            },
            "status": "Available",
            "owner": {
                "id": "58",
                "username": "+96555899184",
                "creation_date": "2017-09-09 18:33:12",
                "info": {
                    "name": "Moneera ibrahim",
                    "email": "Moneeera96@gmail.com",
                    "mobile": "55899184",
                    "store_id": "64",
                    "device_token": null
                },
                "addresses": [
                    {
                        "id": "64",
                        "name": "Store Address",
                        "type": "house",
                        "block_number": "3",
                        "street": "312",
                        "avenue": "",
                        "building": "56",
                        "floor": "",
                        "apartment": "",
                        "directions": "",
                        "lat": "0.000000000000000000",
                        "lng": "0.000000000000000000",
                        "city": {
                            "id": "126",
                            "name": "Saad Al Abdullah",
                            "zone": "9",
                            "governate": "Jahra"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "open": true,
            "next_available": {
                "day_of_week": "Today",
                "start_hour": "1646",
                "end_hour": "2230",
                "day_id": "0",
                "date": "2017-09-17 1646"
            },
            "image": {
                "src": "https://api.bits.com.kw/assets/stores/64/0xqh4.jpg"
            },
            "hours": [
                [
                    {
                        "id": "161",
                        "day_id": "0",
                        "day_of_week": "Sunday",
                        "start_hour": "730",
                        "end_hour": "2230"
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "id": "162",
                        "day_id": "1",
                        "day_of_week": "Monday",
                        "start_hour": "730",
                        "end_hour": "2230"
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "id": "163",
                        "day_id": "2",
                        "day_of_week": "Tuesday",
                        "start_hour": "730",
                        "end_hour": "2230"
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "id": "164",
                        "day_id": "3",
                        "day_of_week": "Wednesday",
                        "start_hour": "730",
                        "end_hour": "2230"
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "id": "165",
                        "day_id": "4",
                        "day_of_week": "Thursday",
                        "start_hour": "730",
                        "end_hour": "2230"
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "id": "166",
                        "day_id": "5",
                        "day_of_week": "Friday",
                        "start_hour": "730",
                        "end_hour": "2230"
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "id": "167",
                        "day_id": "6",
                        "day_of_week": "Saturday",
                        "start_hour": "730",
                        "end_hour": "2230"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have Make POJO class like:

```
    public class StoreModel implements Parcelable{

    @SerializedName("id")
    public int id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;

    @SerializedName("global_delay")
    public String global_delay;

    @SerializedName("approved")
    public boolean approved;

    @SerializedName("min_order")
    public String min_order;

    @SerializedName("has_pickup")
    public int has_pickup;

    @SerializedName("address")
    public AddressModel address;

    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;

    @SerializedName("owner")
    public OwnerModel owner;

    @SerializedName("open")
    public boolean open;

    @SerializedName("next_available")
    public Object next_available;

    @SerializedName("image")
    public ImageModel image;

    protected StoreModel(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        name = in.readString();
        global_delay = in.readString();
        approved = in.readByte() != 0;
        min_order = in.readString();
        has_pickup = in.readInt();
        address = in.readParcelable(AddressModel.class.getClassLoader());
        status = in.readString();
        owner = in.readParcelable(OwnerModel.class.getClassLoader());
        open = in.readByte() != 0;
        image = in.readParcelable(ImageModel.class.getClassLoader());
        //next_available = in.readParcelable(NextAvailableModel.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Creator<StoreModel> CREATOR = new Creator<StoreModel>() {
        @Override
        public StoreModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new StoreModel(in);
        }

        @Override
        public StoreModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new StoreModel[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeInt(id);
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeString(global_delay);
        parcel.writeByte((byte) (approved ? 1 : 0));
        parcel.writeString(min_order);
        parcel.writeInt(has_pickup);
        parcel.writeParcelable(address, i);
        parcel.writeString(status);
        parcel.writeParcelable(owner, i);
        parcel.writeByte((byte) (open ? 1 : 0));
        parcel.writeParcelable(image, i);

        /*if(next_available instanceof NextAvailableModel)
            parcel.writeParcelable((NextAvailableModel)next_available, i);
        else if(next_available instanceof  Boolean)
            parcel.writeByte((byte) ((Boolean)next_available ? 1 : 0));*/
    }

    @SerializedName("hours")
    @Expose
    public List<List<HoursModel>> hours;


}


**And HoursModel Java Class**




    public class HoursModel implements Parcelable{

    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;

    @SerializedName("day_id")
    public String day_id;

    @SerializedName("day_of_week")
    public String day_of_week;

    @SerializedName("start_hour")
    public String start_hour;

    @SerializedName("end_hour")
    public String end_hour;


    protected HoursModel(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readString();
        day_id = in.readString();
        day_of_week = in.readString();
        start_hour = in.readString();
        end_hour = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(id);
        dest.writeString(day_id);
        dest.writeString(day_of_week);
        dest.writeString(start_hour);
        dest.writeString(end_hour);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<HoursModel> CREATOR = new Creator<HoursModel>() {
        @Override
        public HoursModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new HoursModel(in);
        }

        @Override
        public HoursModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new HoursModel[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to convert json in pojo

Comment: Not Working....

Comment: R u getting put the class name and file name miss match error

Comment: @RahulChaudhary No, Actually the problem is only with when GSON trying to parse hour data. Its expected as an array according to POJO class when hours data comes with object, its giving an exception that expected begin with array but found Object

Comment: May explain 2 and 3 in hour object

Comment: Index 0 is Sunday, index 1 is monday and so on..

Comment: @shahid17june Can you please add more code so that I can understand what problem you are getting in setting hours.

Answer (score 0):

First, if possible, verify if you can fix this braindead API. :)

First of all, notice that the API returns 2 very different types of data:

1. list of hours (no keys)
2. map of hours (each element has a key!)

You'll need to represent this structure in your POJO somehow. Maybe a list of key-hour pairs, like `List<Pair<String, Hour>`, with nullable key? Your call.

Second, you need to create a custom `TypeAdapter` that can deserialize a list and/or map into a `Java` object.

Once you have a type adapter, you can either attach it to a field using `@JsonAdapter` annotation, or register custom type in `Gson` builder.

https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html

http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/